# how to filter a particular column with python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file where I have 2 columns: 'Name' and 'size'. The `'Name'` column has multiple file types, namely `".apk, .dat, .vdex, .ttc"` etc. But I only want to populate the files with the file extension ending with .apk. I do not want any other file type in the new excel file.

I have written the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def json_to_excel():
    with open('installed-files.json') as jf:
        data = json.load(jf)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        new_df = df[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
        new_xl = new_df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')
        return new_xl

def filter_apk():  `MODIFIED CODE`
    old_xl = json_to_excel()
    data = pd.read_excel(old_xl)
    a = data[data["Name"].str.contains("\.apk")]
    a.to_excel('zybg.xlsx')
```

Above program does following:

- `json_to_excel()`, takes a Json file, converts it to a .xlsx format and save.
- `filter_apk()` is suppose to create multiple excel file based on the file extension present in "Name" column.

1. 1st function is doing what I intend to.
2. 2nd function is not doing anything. Neither its throwing any error. I have followed this [weblink](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-filter-and-save-the-data-as-new-files-in-excel-with-python-pandas/)

Below are the few samples of the "name" column

```
/system/product/<Path_to>/abc.apk
/system/fonts/wwwr.ttc
/system/framework/framework.jar
/system/<Path_to>/icu.dat
/system/<Path_to>/Normal.apk
/system/<Path_to>/Tv.apk
```

How to get that working? Or is there a better way to achieve the objective?

Please suggest.

ERROR

```
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

Note:

I have all the files at the same location.

### modified code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def json_to_excel():
    with open('installed-files.json') as jf:
        data = json.load(jf)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        new_df = df[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
        new_df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')

def filter_apk():
    json_to_excel()
    old_xl = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx')
    data = pd.read_excel(old_xl)
    a = data[data["Name"].str.contains("\.apk")]
    a.to_excel('zybg.xlsx')


t = filter_apk()
print(t)
```

### New error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/amitesh.sahay/PycharmProjects/work_allocation/TASKS/Jenkins.py", line 89, in <module>
    t = filter_apk()
  File "C:/Users/amitesh.sahay/PycharmProjects/work_allocation/TASKS/Jenkins.py", line 84, in filter_apk
    data = pd.read_excel(old_xl)
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 344, in __init__
    filepath_or_buffer, _, _, _ = get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\amitesh.sahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 243, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Why do you first transform the JSON to an excel file? Can't you just start with the `'installed-files.json'` immediately?

Comment: I did that because there is process which is generating a Json file with all details. Therefore, as an automation process for reporting, I have to first convert the Json to excel and then the 2nd function is intended to work on the specific column "Name"

Comment: Problem is that the name you want to give to your new excel files are in fact a path, so python/pandas thinks you want to save a file named `abc.apk.xlsx` in `/system/product/<Path_to>/`, so it will save it there ór will give an error if that path does not exist.

Comment: Ok, so any solution to achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between your use-case and use-case shown in the [weblink](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-filter-and-save-the-data-as-new-files-in-excel-with-python-pandas/). You want to apply a single filter (apk files), whereas the example you saw had multiple filters which were to be applied one after another (multiple species).

This will do the trick.

```
def filter_apk():
    old_xl = json_to_excel()
    data = pd.read_excel(old_xl)
    a = data[data["Name"].str.contains("\.apk")]
    a.to_excel("<path_to_new_excel>\\new_excel_name.xlsx")
```

Comment: Kunal ,I tried to implement your suggestion. But I am getting error. Added in the main post including the modified code.

Comment: The error is likely coming from json_to_excel function. [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) suggests that to_excel method will not return anything. When you are returning the variable new_xl in that function, try returning path (with the filename included) of the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your new updated question. I guess your first function is not working as you think it is working.

`new_xl = new_df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')`

This will write an excel file, as you are expecting it to do. Which works.

However, assigning it to `new_xl`, does not do anything since there is no return on `pd.to_excel`. So when you return `new_xl` as output of your `json_to_excel` function, you actually return `None`. Therefore in your second function, `old_xl = json_to_excel()` will make `old_xl` have the value `None`.

So, your functions should be something like this:

```
def json_to_excel():
    with open('installed-files.json') as jf:
        data = json.load(jf)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        new_df = df[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
        new_df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')

def filter_apk(): 
    json_to_excel()
    data= pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx')
    a = data[data["Name"].str.contains("\.apk")]
    a.to_excel('zybg.xlsx')
```

Comment: Paul, thank you for your reply. I have modified the program as per your suggestion. But I still get error. add new program and error in main post. Please have a look if you can.

Comment: Did few testing and I have removed the line "data = pd.read_excel(old_xl)". This got rid of the error. But now I am getting "None" as an output

Comment: Issue revolved by removing the line "data = pd.read_excel(old_xl)". The "None" issue was due to the way I was trying to call the function. Instead to assigning the function to a variable. I only called the function.  Thank you

Comment: Sorry, my bad, accidentally called `read_excel` twice, fixed it as well in my answer. If my answer solved your problem please vote and accept as answer, to let other users know this worked.